# Selectively bypassing VPN for certain sites (specifically NetFlix)

Tags: vpn

So with Netflix blocking VPNs I'm wondering if there's a way to allow only NetFlix to bypass the VPN so my other traffic remains private?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on how your VPN is configured. Openvpn lets you exclude certain IP ranges for example, as is described here: [Link](https://forums.openvpn.net/topic8853.html).
The easiest way would probably be to use a SOCKS proxy, since there are various Add-Ons for most browsers that allow you to configure the routing through those in great detail and with an easy user interface.